# What is Mrs Healy drawing on the wall?

Tags: analysis, plot-explanation, orange-is-the-new-black

In season 3 episode 1 of *Orange is the New Black*, there is a flashback where Sam Healy's mother exchanges some dialog with the young Sam Healy.

Essentially the scene is designed to show that Sam Healy's mother was barking mad.

The scene shows her drawing some symbols on the wall, but it goes too fast for me to recognize what they might be alluding to, or even if they have significance.  What are those symbols about?

Or alternatively, are they random scribbles on the wall with no other meaning than to show that Sam's mother was seriously deranged?

Comment: Also, how to mark the start and stop of a text section that might be a spoiler?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was just scribbles/nonsensical doodles, from the looks of it. Below is a still from the episode, if it helps any:

[image]
(Edit: I got the image from [this article.](http://www.sheknows.com/entertainment/articles/1086450/orange-is-the-new-black-season-3-mothers-day-episode) Didn't find it very useful otherwise, but figured I should source the picture.)